# AttributeError when loading function from pickle file in Python script

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, pickle

**Description:**
I'm encountering an `AttributeError` when trying to load a function from a pickle file in my Python script. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```py
import pickle


with open('book_recommendations.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    get_book_recommendations = pickle.load(file)
    cosine_sim_reduced_sample = pickle.load(file)
    df2 = pickle.load(file)
    tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(file)
    svd = pickle.load(file)

book_title = "memior"  # Replace with the desired book title
recommendations = get_book_recommendations(book_title)
print(recommendations)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    get_book_recommendations = pickle.load(file)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'get_book_recommendations' on <module '__main__' from 'app.py'>
```

However, when I run the exact same code in Google Colab, it works fine. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can fix it?
Thank you!

I've checked that the function get_book_recommendations is defined correctly in my script, and it runs without errors in other environments like Google Colab.

Comment: Hey, could you include some sample code to generate the pickle file or provide a download link ?

Comment: sure
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VjSxyQIEc69nBS3mY9nuNzdq40lEAsjT#scrollTo=e026b8a1

Comment: your code is closed